# getting google rank/popularity for keywords

Tags: php, api, search

Is there an api that I can use to check keywords (e.g. Amazon Kindle DX) on Google and return the search popularity or rank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few unofficial APIs to Google Trends listed here:

[http://zoastertech.com/projects/googletrends/?page=Third+party+API+Tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20101111083332/http://zoastertech.com/projects/googletrends/?page=Third+party+API+Tools)

Google announced in 2007 that they would release their own API, but they haven't done it yet.

Comment: This link does not work.

Comment: @Martijn I updated the link to point to the Archive.org cache.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something similar to [this](http://code.google.com/apis/base/docs/2.0/ranking-lang-spec.html)?